# Заглавная письменная буква Ы

Tags: прописная-строчная

Ребенку в школе (3й класс) дали задание. Узнать, как пишется заглавная буква Ы при написании названий городов, например, Ыб. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

Она - прописная - попала в парочку алфавитов: можно списывать!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы посоветовала сделать ещё и петельку, как показано у букв

Ц - Ч - Ш - Щ - Ъ

Answer (score 0):

Изобразить тут письменные буквы нет возможности. Можете посмотреть [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uwtH3BWyFE).